# Trying to show that $\Gamma ( 1/2) = \sqrt{ \pi } $

Tags: probability

Let $\Gamma ( \alpha ) = \int\limits_0^{\infty} x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x} dx $ for $\alpha > 0 $ be gamma function. We can show $\Gamma( \frac{1}{2} ) = \sqrt{ \pi } $. Can we use the chi square distribution of a r.v $X$ to show this fact?

$X$ has chi square probability density function with $p$ degrees of freedom if density of $X$ is given by

$$ f(x) = \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma( \frac{p}{2} ) 2^{\frac{p}{2}} } x^{ \frac{p}{2} - 1} e^{-x} dx $$

where $0 < x < \infty $

Comment: What can you use? For example it's trivial of you are allowed to use the fact that $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$

Comment: I dont understand what you mena

Comment: That formula holds. So if you use that formula for $z=1/2$, you find $\Gamma(1/2)^2 = \pi$

Comment: yeah but I would like to know if there is a way to show this using the density of $X$.

Comment: Ah okay so you're only interestend in a proof that used that fact. My comment is quite useless then :-D

Comment: @Anonaki: your density formula makes no sense (either integral lacks $dx$ - but then the integral is a function of $p$ and not of $x$, or the integral should go away)

Comment: @Anonaki: also, you can probably write $E(X)=1$ and get your result, but given the formula for $f$, clearly $\Gamma(p/2)$ is a normalizing factor and you would probably know something about $\Gamma$ *before* the formula for $f$.

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $x = u^2$, $dx = 2u \, du$, we obtain $$\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}) = \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx = 2 \int_{u=0}^\infty e^{-u^2} \, du.$$  Then the familiar trick of assigning $$I = \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx,$$ so that $$\begin{align*} I^2 
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx \int_{y=0}^\infty e^{-y^2} \, dy \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=0}^\infty e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \int_{r=0}^\infty e^{-r^2} r \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \left[ -\frac{e^{-r^2}}{2} \right]_{r=0}^\infty \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \end{align*}$$ yields $I = \sqrt{\pi}/2$, hence $$\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$$ as claimed.